# PyCharm: code completion for monkey patching

Tags: python, pycharm, monkeypatching

I'm wondering if it's possible to get PyCharm to support code completion for monkey patched functions?

I have the following class:

```
class _PathExt(Path):

    def ensure_exists(self):
        if not self.exists():
            if not self.parent.exists():
                os.makedirs(self.parent.absolute(), exist_ok=True)
            os.makedirs(self.absolute())
        return self

    def subdir(self, sub_name):
        return Path(os.path.join(self.absolute(), sub_name))
```

Which I then monkey patch with:

```
def monkey_patch(from_type, to_type):
    for name in [x for x in dir(from_type) if not x.startswith('_') and x not in dir(to_type)]:
        value = from_type.__getattribute__(from_type, name)
        if inspect.isfunction(value):
            setattr(to_type, name, value)


monkey_patch(_PathExt, Path)
```

It's understandable that this wouldn't work as it's dynamic, so I then tried:

```
Path.subdir = _PathExt.subdir
```

But still PyCharm won't detect it. Is this possible at all?

Edit:

In this specific case I've decided to derive my class from `Path` and then import my class with an `as` alias, so it's a drop in replacement, but I'd still like to know if anything can be done to support monkey patching in PyCharm.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't anything native (re: magic) to pycharm that supports this.  I'm wondering if a replacement typeshed would work in this case.